# Does grub need to update/refresh after install windows into another hard drive?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, drive

i have a pc with two physical disks: one of them with debian wheezy; and the other one has one logical partition with several data and some free space. The thing is, if i install windows 7 x64 in this free space (remember that linux is installed in the other phisical disk), is there any problem with grub? Does grub need to update/refresh? or once windows finish installing, automatically grub will show me both OS for booting?

Comment: At the minimum you will have to run sudo update-grub. AT the worst, Windows will destroy your Linux install. Windows installs a 100MB boot partition to the drive set as boot with BIOS (if not UEFI). And if you have BIOS set to boot Linux drive, it just uses the first 100MB and creates new partition table in effect wiping your Linux drive. Be sure to set in BIOS to boot from Windows drive first. Or disconnect Linux drive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to update grub. You can update grub by running '$ sudo update-grub'. See [GRUB could not find Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu - RAID 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178647/grub-could-not-find-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu-raid-0)

I highly suggest you detach the debian wheezy disk when you install windows, since windows may try to overwrite the bootloader on your debian disk. You may be able to recover your bootloader using an ubuntu disk by looking here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows if you do end up overwriting the bootloader on the debian disk, but your best bet is to disconnect the debian disk before installing windows.